# Lof K2Scroller Module

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

I have been using K2 Scroller module developed by Land of Coder. When I use this module to display same category items in the items view the module displays items in the ascending order of the date created and it is the default and only setting available in the module parameter settings in the back-end. However, I want the module to display the items in date wise descending order. So I chose to edit the default code in the helper which I suppose is used to process items based on the back-end settings. And this is the part of the code in the helper file which I think controls the order:

```
public function __getList( $params ){
            global $mainframe;

                         /*some irrelevant code removed*/

                        $condition     = $this->buildConditionQuery( $params );
            $limitDescriptionBy = $params->get('limit_description_by','char');
            $ordering      = $params->get( 'k2_ordering', 'created_desc'); 
            $limit         = $params->get( 'limit_items',  5 );
            $ordering      = str_replace( '_', '  ', $ordering );
            $my            = &JFactory::getUser();
            $aid           = $my->get( 'aid', 0 );

                        /*some irrelevant code removed*/

            $extraURL       = $params->get('open_target')!='modalbox'?'':'&tmpl=component'; 
            $excludeIds     = $params->get('exclude_ids', '');
            $db     = &JFactory::getDBO();
            $date   =& JFactory::getDate();
            $now    = $date->toMySQL();
            $dateFormat = $params->get('date_format', 'DATE_FORMAT_LC3');

            $limitDescriptionBy = $params->get('limit_description_by','char');
            $isAuthor= $params->get('itemAuthor',0);
            require_once ( JPath::clean(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_k2/helpers/route.php') );
            $query = "SELECT a.*, cr.rating_sum/cr.rating_count as rating, c.name as categoryname,
                            c.id as categoryid, c.alias as categoryalias, c.params as categoryparams, cc.commentcount as commentcount".
                    " FROM #__k2_items as a".
                        " LEFT JOIN #__k2_categories c ON c.id = a.catid" .
                        " LEFT JOIN #__k2_rating as cr ON a.id = cr.itemid".
                        " LEFT JOIN (select cm.itemid  as id, count(cm.id) as commentcount from #__k2_comments as cm
                                                                    where cm.published=1 group by cm.itemid) as cc on a.id = cc.id";

            $query .= " WHERE a.published = 1"
                        . " AND a.access get('featured_items_show','0') == 0 ){
                $query.= " AND a.featured != 1";
            } elseif(  $params->get('featured_items_show','0') == 2 ) {
                $query.= " AND a.featured = 1";
            }
            if( trim($excludeIds) ){
                $query .= " AND a.id NOT IN(".$excludeIds.") ";
            }
            $query .=  $condition . ' ORDER BY ' . $ordering;   
            $query .=  $limit ? ' LIMIT ' . $limit : '';

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $data = $db->loadObjectlist();

            /*some irrelevant code removed*/

                        return $data;   
        }


        /**
         * build condition query base parameter  
         * 
         * @param JParameter $params;
         * @return string.
         */
        public  function buildConditionQuery( $params ){
            $source = trim($params->get( 'k2_source', 'k2_category' ) );
            if( $source == 'k2_category' ){
                $catids = $params->get( 'k2_category','');

                if( !$catids ){
                    return '';
                }
                $catids = !is_array($catids) ? $catids : '"'.implode('","',$catids).'"';
                $condition = ' AND  a.catid IN( '.$catids.' )';
            } else {
                $ids = preg_split('/,/',$params->get( 'k2_items_ids',''));  
                $tmp = array();
                foreach( $ids as $id ){
                    $tmp[] = (int) trim($id);
                }
                $condition = " AND a.id IN('". implode( "','", $tmp ) ."')";
            }
            return $condition;
        }
```

Am I editing the right part of the code or am I missing something else.

I am looking forward to your help

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way would be to modify the xml file of the module.

I looked at the code of Lof K2Scroller (v 2.2 for Joomla 2.5) and the different ordering options are there.

However if you want to modify the default option, you are in the right file, just replace 'created_desc' for 'created_asc' .

Comment: Thanks Shaz. I have actually modified the default option but it just doesn't work. Can you please tell me what needs to be edited in the xml file?